# alfresco outbound email behind firewall

Tags: email, smtp, alfresco, firewall

I'm trying to configure the outbound mail service on alfresco behind a firewall, I add the mail configuration on alfresco-global.properties but it can connect to the remote smtp server, there's a connection timed out error in the log. I guess I need to open the correct port but which one?

Comment: you have configuration like this.      

mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.port=465
mail.encoding=UTF-8
mail.username="mymailid"
mail.password="mymailpassword"
mail.protocol=smtps                                                                                          
mail.from.default="mymailid"
mail.smtps.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtps.auth=true

Comment: yes I have that in the properties file

Comment: have you made that email id less secure?

Comment: the thing is on another server without a firewall it works

Comment: if you have your own smtp server then you have to enable that smtp port in firewall.

Comment: it is not my own smtp. Let's say I use gmail smtp, alfresco uses a java class to connect to smtp.gmail.com on the destination port 465, I need the source port

Comment: The source port will be randomly assigned from any free one by default. Only the destination port is predictable. You'll need to tell your firewall to allow your server to make outbound email connections

Comment: that's what I've done, but still doesn't work. After trying others things I believe that the problem is not the firewall but rather the reverse proxy. Thanks everyone for the help